# Is there a better way to code if within if statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es5-shim

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to write this javascript code. `if` within `if` seems pretty average. Happy to use `es5/es6` if possible. Basically, I'm checking to see if a variable exists, if it does exist I want to make sure the url contains `https` and update it if it doesn't.

```
if (blogURL) {
  if (!/^https?:\/\//i.test(blogURL)) {
      var blogURL = 'http://' + blogURL;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `&&` to test both conditions in a single `if` statement and remove the `var` as you presumably just want to update the existing variable.

Comment: Oh so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&&` to test both conditions in a single `if` statement and remove the var as you presumably just want to update the existing variable, not look like you're trying to define a new variable.

```
if (blogURL && !/^https?:\/\//i.test(blogURL)) {
     blogURL = 'http://' + blogURL;
}
```

This works because if the first conditional test fails, then the second conditional test is not executed.  This is a common way to do something like this in Javascript.

Comment: @bp123 - OK, hopefully blogURL never starts with something like `file://`. or just `/somepath`.

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right there. I'm asking for a web address in a form. So I'd assume no one is putting `file://` there.

Comment: One question here. My IDE is using ESLint. It highlights the `http://' as an error `unexpected string concatenation. prefer-template)`. Is there another way to write that?

Comment: @bp123 - That seems like an overzealous ESLint warning.  You could certainly use an ES6 string template, but for just prepending a constant, there is really no reason.

Comment: Yeah, new to ESlint. The docs for meteor suggest using air-bnb eslint which has put errors everywhere in my code. So much to learn.

Comment: @bp123 - You are probably not using the backquote character as the string delineator.  Please look carefully at my example and you can read about template literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

```
if (blogURL && (!/^https?:\/\//i.test(blogURL)))
{
  var blogURL = 'http://' + blogURL;
}
```

Combine your conditions with && operator. Because && evaluates from left to right, it will test next condition only if previous is/are true.

Answer (score 0):

Can always do an inline `if` statement:

```
var exist = blogURL != null ? !/^https?:\/\//i.test(blogURL) : false;

if(exist){

}
```

Or the `&&` as others have recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This is one line most optimized neat and clean solution:

```
blogURL = (blogURL && !blogURL.startsWith("https://")) ? ('http://' + blogURL) : blogURL;
```